# Drupal Commerce: Allow anonymous users to choose their username on checkout

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

The default setup includes a single option in the "Account Information" pane which allows for an email address. The user's username is then derived from that.

I would like to add another field for "Username" where the user can enter their own username, instead of having it generated for them automatically based off of their email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a sandbox project [here](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/purushothaman.drupalgeeks/2115745) that you will need to download with git that looks like a complete sign up form.

Theres also [Commerce User Profile Pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_user_profile_pane) that allows you to choose the fields in the pane. Ive not used it before, but looks like a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both of these options. Problems with both, the sandbox project makes you register before you checkout, I just want to add in an extra field to save it as their username. The Commerce User Profile Pane adds a new pane, but not to the Account Information pane. So it's not quite what I want either.

Comment: Ah that's a shame, they were the closest I could find.

Comment: I made a couple adjustments to the sandbox project to get it working.  Best solution I could get working. Not perfect but it will do. Thanks @Collins